# Knockout observableArray foreach doesn't work

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, ko.observablearray

I'm beginner in Knockout and I need some help here.

I sliced some part of my code, which I can't understand, why it doesn't work.

http://jsbin.com/ezuKume/1/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an updated [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/ezuKume/4/edit?html,js,output) for you.

You were doing a `foreach` on a `<tr>` element, but your `data-bind` was in a `<div>`. It should be either a `<table>` or a `<tbody>`